# In microservice archticture, i have microservice which have user detail but in zuul API gateway i want to authenticate my requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, microservices

microservices architecture
I have a  micro service(userservice:user related microservice) but in Zuul API gateway application i want to authenticate requests for all microservices and use spring security. I have to create signin and signup requests(AuthController) in Zuul application which require datasources,userRepository all things in zuul application.

If i use userservice(microservice  user related)for other user related requests then i have use same datasource and create duplicate beans and repository for same data source which i already created in zuul api gateway application ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel it would be a good design to authenticate usenames and passwords at gateway level. Instead what you can do is, you can add JWT tokens which can validate the request itself in zuul filters. This can be one level of verification at gateway level.
Second, you can implement caching at api level which would significantly increase the throughput of your backend security api.